# How to coordinate axis span from the data?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is necessary to get out of it.

[image]

This:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={anchor=east,rotate=90},
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day.\month.\year},
    table/col sep = semicolon,
    height = 0.3\paperheight, 
    width = 0.5\paperwidth,
    xmin=2015-10-01,
    xmax=2015-12-31,
    ymin=30,
    ymax=55,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    no markers,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
]
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma] {oil_prices.csv};
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=2, col sep=comma] {oil_prices.csv};  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\addlegendentry{something cyrillic}` after the corresponding `\addplot`.

Comment: or `\legend{first entry, second entry}` after all plots.

Comment: or `legend entries={first entry,second entry}` in the `axis` options. See section 4.9.4 *Legends* in the manual.